# Error AADSTS50105 if the user is member of a group that is a member of another group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric

We have successfully set up AAD authentication for an existing Service Fabric cluster using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-setup-aad). However, we have some issues when it comes to assigning groups to the application:

- Connect with a user that has the admin role directly assigned ✔
- Connect with a user that is member of a group which is directly assigned to the admin role ✔
- Connect with a user that is member of a **group which is member of the group** which is directly assigned to the admin role ❌

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS50105: The signed in user
> '{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000 -

AzureActiveDirectory -ServerCertThumbprint yyy
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
False
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : GetAccessToken failed:
authority=https://login.microsoftonline.com/zzz
cluster=xxx client=yyy
error=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS50105: The signed in user
'{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application
'xxx'(myclustername).
Trace ID: <traceid>
Correlation ID: <correlationId>
Timestamp: 2020-09-01 16:03:00Z
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask[T](Task`1 task)
   at System.Fabric.AzureActiveDirectory.Client.ClientUtility.GetAccessToken(String authority, String audience, String
client, String redirectUri, Boolean refreshSession)
   at GetAccessToken(Char* authority, Char* audience, Char* client, Char* redirectUri, Boolean refreshSession, Char*
outBuffer, Int32 outBufferSize)
        ErrorCode: access_denied
        StatusCode: 0
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint xxx.westeurop ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

I tried both via Service Fabric Explorer and Powershell (`Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`). Service Fabric Explorer just freezes after logging in, while Powershell gives the error mentioned above.

Am I hitting a limit for what is possible, or is it possible to allow this?

[image: Screenshot of assigned users and groups]

Comment: Navigate to the `Overview` of your group, check if its type is `Microsoft 365` or `Security`?

Comment: The type is "Security". "Only users and security groups can be assigned..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested groups are not supported for group based assignments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-saasapps

> Group-based assignment is supported only for security groups. Nested group memberships are not supported for group-based assignment to applications at this time.